# Lighting artifacts for very small objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine

For very small objects (micrometer range), which nearly touch each other, I encountered the following artifacts:

[image: Image of artifacts for small particles.]

To me, they look like the result of some sort of cut-off for the raytracing.

I tried to play around with bounces, but to no avail.

Is there another solution (e.g. some sort of scale setting for the raytracing), apart from changing the size of the particles themselves?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try scaling up? I don’t know why you really need the exact unit…but working with „normal“ scaling works usually…

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Scaling up would probably work. However, I'd like to keep physically accurate dimensions, to not impact things like the mass of objects for rigid body simulations, etc.